# WCF service host by IIS, spring.net scope="request"

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, spring.net

I would like to enable the `scope="request"` attribute in my xml configuration:

```
<object id="IDataAccess" type="Dal.DataAccess, Dal" scope="request">
```

My WCF service is hosted on IIS and I use `RouteTable` and `ServiceHostFactory` to create my service:

```
static void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("url", serviceHostFactory, typeof(MyService)));
}
```

I added the `WebContextHandler` in my `web.config` to enable the scope `request` and `session` as described here http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/web.htm (section 22.3.1)

```
<sectionGroup name="spring">
  <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebContextHandler, Spring.Web"/>
</sectionGroup>
```

And the `httpModules` thing:

```
 <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="*" path="*.aspx" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
    </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

And because I am on window 7, framework Net 4.0 I also added:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="Spring" type="Spring.Context.Support.WebSupportModule, Spring.Web"/>
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I did all that. and it doesn't work, I still have:

```
Resource handler for the 'web' protocol is not defined.
```

when it calls:

```
SpringContext = (IApplicationContext)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("spring/context");
```

I don't what to do now, can someone from the Spring.net community help me. It doesn't look like I try to do something tricky or hacky. It is a common pattern to host a WCF service in IIS.

**EDIT**:

I tried with

```
<add verb="*" path="*" type="Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory, Spring.Web"/>
```

as suggested in comments and it doesn't work.

Comment: You only seem to add a handler for *.aspx resources.

Comment: well, I must that I don't know really what I did, what is exactly a handler ? I just copy the lines from the Spring configuration. How can I enable handler for all resources ? by setting path="*". I'll give it a try

Comment: The `Spring.Web.Support.PageHandlerFactory` is a factory for `Spring.Web.Page`s, so I don't think you can use it for your wcf endpoints. I'm afraid I know too little wcf at this stage to help out further, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked a bot at the spring source code and if I add

```
ResourceHandlerRegistry.RegisterResourceHandler("web", typeof (WebResource));
```

in my `Application_Start` method, before getting the ContextConfiguration, it does the job. I have no idea why. I think it is a bug in the current `WebSupportModule`.

It is very strange because this is called in the static constructor of `WebSupportModule`. I tried to enable logging for Spring, but the log file is created, but stay empty :/ it could have helped me a bit more to understand.

Comment: Nice find, +1. With respect to logging using spring.net: [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475888/can-spring-net-log-what-its-doing-as-it-constructors-objects) might help.